# How to show UTC for time range search in Application Insights?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I notice that the time range for Application Insights Search functionality is using my local timezone. Is there a way to set the time range to use UTC instead?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, Application Insights allows user to select whether to search by Local Timezone or UTC/GMT

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems not support to show UTC time in `Time range`.

Workaround:

Select your filter conditions first, go to `Analytics`, you will find the time in the query will be UTC time like `requests | extend itemType = iif(itemType == 'request',itemType,"") | where (itemType == 'request' and (timestamp >= datetime(2018-12-06T06:36:00.000Z) and timestamp <= datetime(2018-12-07T06:36:00.000Z))) | top 101 by timestamp desc` , then you can modify the time -> `Run`.

In the result, select `CHART`, you will see the result with UTC time.

[image]

Comment: Hmm that seems to be a workaround to query buy UTC, but in Analytics, I cannot view the End-to-end transaction. Anyway, thanks for the response

Comment: @Nyamnyam Glad it helps.